# Pie Chart control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-3.0, pie-chart

Is it possible to reduce the width of data point line in 3D Pie chart graph in asp.net?
[Please check the image, you can able to see red color round, i want to reduce width of this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLmN9.jpg)

Please check the code behind it:

```
             style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF">
            <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" class="body">
                <asp:Chart ID="ChartOnBDomesticByLocationType" runat="server"
                    BackImageTransparentColor="224, 224, 224" 
                    TextAntiAliasingQuality="SystemDefault" BackSecondaryColor="Snow"
                    BorderlineColor="Silver" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" BorderlineWidth="2">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" BorderWidth="4" YValuesPerPoint="10" Name="Series1"
                            MarkerSize="2" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt, style=Bold" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"
                            BackImageTransparentColor="192, 0, 0" IsXValueIndexed="True" ChartArea="ChartArea3"
                            Legend="On Board" 
                            CustomProperties="PieLineColor=DimGray, CollectedSliceExploded=True, MinimumRelativePieSize=50, PieLabelStyle=Outside, 3DLabelLineSize=30">
                        </asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" BorderWidth="4" YValuesPerPoint="10" Name="Series2"
                            MarkerSize="2" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt, style=Bold" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"
                            BackImageTransparentColor="192, 0, 0" IsXValueIndexed="True" ChartArea="ChartArea3"
                            Legend="On Board" 
                            CustomProperties="PieLineColor=LightGray, 3DLabelLineSize=30" 
                            LabelForeColor="White">
                            <EmptyPointStyle MarkerBorderColor="White" MarkerColor="DimGray" 
                                MarkerSize="1" />
                        </asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea3" BorderWidth="7" BackColor="White" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom"
                            BackImageTransparentColor="128, 128, 255" BackSecondaryColor="White" ShadowColor="RoyalBlue"
                            >
                            <AxisY Interval="10" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt"
                                TitleForeColor="ForestGreen">
                                <MajorGrid LineColor="Gray" />
                                <LabelStyle Format="0" />
                            </AxisY>
                            <AxisX LineColor="Red" LineWidth="0" TitleForeColor="Black" >
                                <MajorGrid LineWidth="0" LineColor="Gray" />
                            </AxisX>
                          <%--  <Area3DStyle Inclination="20" PointDepth="12" Rotation="20" LightStyle="None" 
                                WallWidth="10" IsRightAngleAxes="False" Perspective="15" />--%>
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="samplechartarea" BackColor="224, 224, 224" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom"
                            BackImageTransparentColor="0, 192, 0" BackSecondaryColor="224, 224, 224" ShadowColor="Lime"
                            Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true">
                            <AxisY Interval="10" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt"
                                IsMarginVisible="False" TitleForeColor="ForestGreen" Title="PreServiceCatalog">
                                <MajorGrid LineColor="Gray" />
                            </AxisY>
                            <AxisX LineColor="Red" LineWidth="0" TitleForeColor="ForestGreen">
                                <MajorGrid LineWidth="0" LineColor="Gray" />
                            </AxisX>
```

```
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                    <Legends>
                        <asp:Legend Name="On Board" Title="Office Location" Docking="Bottom" 
                            Alignment="Center" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 9pt, style=Bold" 
                            IsTextAutoFit="False">
                        </asp:Legend>
                    </Legends>
                    <%--<Titles>
                        <asp:Title Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" ShadowOffset="10" Alignment="TopCenter"
                            IsDockedInsideChartArea="False" ForeColor="Black" DockedToChartArea="ChartArea3"
                            Name="Title1" Text="Domestic OnBoarding By Location Type" Docking="Top" BackColor="White"
                            BorderColor="DarkGreen">
                            <Position Height="5.063335" Width="52.16632" X="4.365" Y="3" />
                        </asp:Title>
                    </Titles>--%>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282600/change-asp-chart-legend-label-width, though no answer on that. I don't have VS2010 installed any longer, but I seem to recall these label lines share attributes with the Border entity, have you tried setting BorderWidth = 1?

Comment: Yes, I resolved my issue , My setting the border width inside the chart area.